# path.py not recognized in eclipse

Tags: python, eclipse

I installed the path package:

```
easy_install path.py
```

running ipython I can validly run:

```
from path import path
```

Eclipse (after restart) does not recognize this (unresolved import "path").
It also will not auto-complete class members and functions.

Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: Is it PyDev? Try to add path to forced buildins in interpreter properties

Answer (score 1):

Accroding to [PyDev FAQ](http://pydev.org/faq.html#PyDevFAQ-IhavealibraryinstalledandPyDevdoesnotfindit):

> ### I have a library installed and PyDev does not find it
>
> Well, problems have been reported on Mac and Linux, and the main
>   reason seems to be symlinks. PyDev will only find extensions that are
>   'really' below the python install directory. This happens because the
>   'less common denominator', which in this case is windows, does not
>   have symlinks. A workaround to this problem includes **manually adding
>   the given folder installation to the pythonpath** or **changing the
>   installation of the package to be under the site-packages folder.**

Answer (score 0):

Just try right click on `Project` and set PYTHONPAH property manually